# To what extent has functional analysis been used in understanding neural networks?

Tags: neural-networks

Has the family of models encapsulated by neural networks been studied from a functional analysis perspective? Are there any general theorems, results, etc. about neural networks from this perspective?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_approximation_theorem

Comment: http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap4.html

Answer (score 3):

Probably the core appeal of neural networks is the so-called "universal approximation theorem". Loosely stated, it's possible to use a neural network to approximate a continuous function on a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ using only a single hidden layer and finitely many neurons.

The *continuous* and *compact* portions of that statement are the immediately obvious caveats. Other caveats include those related to actually *training* the neural network: it may not be easy to train achieve a specific precision because training neural networks is hard.

More information can be found in Chapter 4 of *Neural Networks and Deep Learning* by Michael Nielsen. Wikipedia has a formal statement of the theorem.